# Configurable Products Not Showing in Search or Catalog

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1. I have set up a Configurable Product and created several associated products using the quick simple product creation.  The simple products are all "enabled" and "not visible individually"  .  I have inventory showing "in stock" with a quantity for all simple products.

Yet the configurable product is not visible in my catalog or in search.

Ideas what I am missing??? 
Checked the manual, etc.  and everything seems to be setup correctly.

### edit

Within the configurable product, inside the associated products tab, Should the simple products be listed at the bottom?

For some reason, I am not showing any item skus and the search always comes up "blank" even though I search for a SKU that is available.

Steve

Comment: i have the same exact issue.
under associated products tab in simple products, can't find the sku of the simple product. (though the item exists). this happened two months ago when all of a sudden all configurable products lost their simple products association and the solution was to revert back to a backup. glad its happening to more person than one. if anyone knows what's up, please chip in

Comment: I'm having the same problem, even when I create the simple products using quick create. They show in the list until I save the parent product.

Answer (score 4):

In your configurable product, there is an attribute with name `Visibility`. You need to set it to `Catalog, Search`. This would make your product visible in search. You may probably forgot to do it.

1. So go to `Catalog  >  Manage Products`.
2. Select the configurable product. Under `General` tab, set `Visibility` to `Catalog, Search`.
3. Make sure product is assigned with current store and website.(Go to `websites` and `categories` tabs to do this).
4. Clear all cache and
5. Reload the page and then search.

Comment: The configurable Product is already set toi "enabled" and "Catalog, Search" for Visibility.

Comment: I then did it again to make sure..  and I am still getting the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

you need to manually run an indexer on "Catalog Search Index" to make sure new / changed products show up in search results

Also, yes you MUST have the simple products listed in the the associated products tab.

```
For some reason, I am not showing any item skus and the search always comes up "blank" even though I search for a SKU that is available.
```

sounds like when you do your search you overlook the all-important drop-down on the left of the search box.  If the drop-Down box says "Yes" the search will return ONLY the products that are ALREADY associated with the configurable.  if it says no, the opposite happens.  I usually set it to "Any"

Comment: I've tried re-indexing (both through admin and though the indexer.php in the shell), and the drop-down is set to any. I created the products through the quick create and they show in the "Super product attributes configuration" section until I save the parent product.

Comment: @provence shop.. Once i set manually run an indexer on "Catalog Search Index".products will shown in  search result  or need to "Catalog Search Index" manually every changes in product add/modification section. kindly clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with this:
your attributes set must be applicable to `all product types` or almost `Simple Product and Configurable Product`

credits to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755331/391787

Answer (score 0):

For people who still have this problem after following Rajeev's instructions.

Try the following:

1. Go to the configurable product. Under `Inventory` tab, set `Stock Availability` to `In Stock`.
2. Clear all cache and reload page.