# Magento 1.9 search not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch

Searching is not working for new added products, though it's working for old products.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you reindex once , atleast for `search index` index by `system >  index Management`.....

Comment: Done, still not working.

Comment: is products visible if you open by url, means `sitename.com/product-url.html`

Comment: Yes. I can find it it category too. I just can't search for it.

Comment: and product should not be out-of-stock as well as quantity must be more than 0

Comment: It is for sure. Item is in stock and quantity is more than 0. Customers can buy it if they navigate to it using top navigation  by going to category. But they just can't find it using search.

Comment: are you using any 3rd party extension for `search` or default magento `search` ?

Comment: Hymm, I am not sure, just took over from someone but there might be a extension involved. How can I check that?

Comment: @GrzegorzWisniewski go to `app/etc/modules` and check any search related extensions available , also you can check that by backend in `system> Advanced > Advanced` menu.....

Comment: I can see Mirasvit SearchSphinx in app/etc/modules with <active>true</active>. I also found Magpleasure_Searchcore

Comment: @GrzegorzWisniewski those `Mirasvit` guys are awesome. well, this will help you : https://mirasvit.com/doc/ssu/2.3.2/ , go to `Search > Manage Search Indexes` and reindex that too..... also you can chat with them and aks for help..... you may get solution soon.....

Comment: @GrzegorzWisniewski check in `Magpleasure_Searchcore` , is `<active>true</active> or <active>false</active>`

Comment: It is `<active>true</active>`

Comment: @GrzegorzWisniewski its better to use one extension  , is both extension are enabled in `system> Advanced > Advanced menu` ?

Comment: Yes, they both are enabled. Disable one? Which one?

Comment: @GrzegorzWisniewski i have no idea about `Magpleasure_Searchcore` , but for my experience `Mirasvit` is really nice and paid one..... before disabling another extension, you can try reindexing by `Search > Manage Search Indexes` if it is available in backend......

Comment: @BabyinMagento I have disabled `Magpleasure_Searchcore` and left the `Mirasvit` extension on. Reindexed `Search > Manage Search Indexes` and also `System > Index Managment` but still no luck....

Comment: @GrzegorzWisniewski the last option is please visit : https://mirasvit.com/  and chat with them , right now they are available for chat, i am sure they will help you.......

Comment: @BabyinMagento I will do! Thanks a lot for you help and interest! Lets see what they have to say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the issue was. As I am using a 3-rd party extension (Sphinx search by Mirasvit) the configuration was not properly set. Previous employer made really difficult configuration where search engine was set to be hosted on a external server, not maintained by anyone. Changing it to build in search engine solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You gave to select ***Catalog,Search*** option in **Visibility** field. Thats reason new added products are not displaying in search result.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your interest. I had a look and it is already catalog,search in visibility search.

Comment: ok. try by clean,refresh cache and reindexing

Comment: Already done. Still not working. I can find the product by looking into the category but search is not working.

Comment: Ok. Duplicate any OLD product and rename that. Check if that loading in search? In this way you can compare setting as well.

Comment: I have duplicated old iteam and renamed, reindexed and cleared cache but it is still not displaying so I don't think it is related to the settings.

Comment: Did you check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86059/29175

Comment: I had a look and it is set to apply to all products.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60582/discussion-between-grzegorz-wisniewski-and-jai).

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm following points with your new products according to Store View,

Status =  Enabled

Visibility = Catalog, Search

Stock Availability = In Stock

Qty = Greater than 0

Categories =  Category associated

And also make sure same setting applied for **Website** and **Store view**
you can check through the **Choose Store View** option.

Hope it will help